# Is there `hot reload` feature in Android Studio native Java app development?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Does Android Studio have `hot reload` feature for native Java app development?
I am working on somewhat large application and it takes long time to rebuild so I am searching for some way to make it faster.

Answer (score 10):

There is something really similiar called `Instant Run` for target devices that run `Android 8.0` or later. In `Android Studio` there is a button right next to the run icon and it will apply your changes without rebuilding the entire app from scratch. In newer AS versions the button is simply called `Apply Changes`.

However, speaking from personal experience this feature is **nowhere near as reliable and fast as for instance, Flutters "Hot Reload"** and sometimes it will simply not work. In such cases you will have to rebuild the entire app.

Here is the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes) for `Apply Changes`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Running Devices` tab there is an option called `Live Edit`. You can configure it to `push updates automatically`.

In the `Settings` window you can find it here: `Editor -> Live Edit`

[image: Android Studio - Running Devices Tab]

Comment: i think that just for jetpack compose